# How to extend a Barbados tourist visa?

Tags: visas, visa-extensions, barbados

I've only stayed in Barbados for up to 30 days but I know my parents have stayed there for far longer than that a few times, by extending their visas.

How do you extend a bajan tourist visa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply for the extension in a few different ways, a [Barbados Tourist site](https://barbados.org/docs_duration.htm#.XbGFHEVKh-U) states:

> Should you wish to extend your stay in Barbados, you can apply for an
>   extension via the Barbados Immigration Department - tel (246)
>   426-1011, email immigration@barbados.gov.bb.

The official site also gives a [list of documents](http://www.immigration.gov.bb/pages/Extension.aspx) that must be provided to process this extension:

> Persons requesting a period longer than the time previously granted
>   can make an application to the Immigration Department at the
>   Headquarters.
>
> Requirements:
>
> - $100.00 application fee
> - Valid ticket for duration of stay
> - Valid
>     passport
> - One (1) Photo
> - Any other document to support the application (
>     eg Doctor’s letter, etc)
> - Spouses of long term work permit holders who
>     are applying for an extension of stay must produce a Police
>     Certificate of Character (PCC)
> - A copy of the bio-data page of the
>     applicant’s valid passport